# Can Chrome Extensions decode custom IPv6 packets?

Tags: c++, sockets, google-chrome, tcp, network-programming

So Can I decode ipv6 tcp packages that use the experimental "Next Header" of 253/254 instead of 6, by writing a Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 0):

No. IP headers are intended for internal use by the network stack, and are not generally passed on to userspace applications such as Chrome.